# JavaScript override specific jso properties

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object that contains base options. If that object is initialized with a specific new option, I only want to change the one that was specified.

```js
//Object :

var controller = function (){

    var _id = id;
    var _options = {
        placeholder: "Search..."
        value: "Some text",
        width: 25,
        ...
    };

    // ==================================
    //          Public Functions
    // ==================================
    return {

        init: function (id, options = null) {
            ...

        }

    }
}();
```

**Example** here i only change the `placeholder` property.

```
Call: controller.init('demo', options = { placeholder: 'Other value...' });

Expected change: 
_options = {
    placeholder: "Other value..."
    value: "Some text",
    width: 25,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Use `Object.assign`? Did you try something?

Comment: why not just use a JS class, it will give you modern and clean code ?

Comment: @MisterJojo not compatible with the browser version where this app is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `...` to merge the provided options into the default options.

```js
var controller = function() {

  var _id = id;
  var _options = {
    placeholder: "Search..."
    value: "Some text",
    width: 25,
    // ...
  };

  // ==================================
  //          Public Functions
  // ==================================
  return {

    init: function(id, options = {}) {
      this.options = {..._options, ...options};
      // ...
    }

  }
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code.

_options = Object.assign(_options, options);

Here, _options will have default properties and values. options is input property with limited configuration. So, From this code, _options get only overuse with options properties.

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Object assign works too.

```js
const thingy = (() => {
  let myWords = {
    favorite: "defenestrate",
    leastFavorite: "whilst",
    newest: "copacetic",
    oldest: "dada",
  };
  return (words) => {
    myWords = Object.assign(myWords, words);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myWords));
  }
})();

// For the demo.
thingy({newest: "pyroclastic", fakest: "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"});
```